# Prove that if $ 0 \leq u_{n+1} \leq \frac{u_n + \epsilon_n}{K}$ then $\lim u_n = 0$.

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Given that
$K > 1$. And that
$\lim \epsilon_n = 0 $ such that $ \epsilon_n > 0 $.
Also $ u_n \in [0,1]$, such that
$ 0 \leq u_{n+1} \leq \frac{u_n + \epsilon_n}{K}$.

Prove that $\lim u_n = 0$.

There is an incredibly complicated solution using epsilons and summations in my textbook, but I thought of something much simpler.

Just take the limit of $ \lim 0 \leq \lim u_{n+1} \leq \lim \frac{u_n + \epsilon_n}{K}$, we get $ 0 \leq l \leq \frac{l}{K}$, such that $\lim u_n = l$. But $l \leq \frac{l}{K}$ implies $l \times( K - 1 )\leq 0$, since $u_n \geq 0$ and $ K > 1$, this clearly implies that $l=0$.

Is this solution correct?

Comment: The solution is not correct. You have implicitly assumed that the limit exists. You need to first prove the limit exists. If you can do that, then yes, your proof is good; however in the process of proving the limit exists you will prove the limit is zero, so this argument will be unnecessary.

Comment: @User8128 How can I show that the limit exists? I did not understand the solution provided in my textbook.

Comment: @mmmmhmmmmmh Consider replacing $\lim$ by $\limsup$ in your argument.

Comment: You need to go back to the definition: take $\varepsilon > 0$ and show that there exists $N\in \mathbb N$ such that $\vert u_n\vert < \varepsilon$ for all $n \ge N$.

Comment: José Avilez said something pretty simple. The only thing that is left to us is to prove the boundness of the sequences. But note that, If $u_k\leq u_0 + \sup \epsilon_k$ then $u_{k+1} \leq u_0 + \sup \epsilon_k$ as well. This proves boundness since the first element is bounded by something of this form. Now, your argument could be used to take the limsup in both sides of the inequality. To make it more precise take the sup of all the elements above k in both sides, and then take the limit. Since this sequence converges (because It converges to limsup), your argument preserves